# How to write to database without quotation marks, java

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write to my firebase database without quotation marks in the values. Below is my code when writing to the database. What do i need to add to remove quotation marks.

The image shows what I am currently getting in my database:

[image: the image shows what I am currently getting in my database]

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            TravelDetails travelDetails = new TravelDetails();
            GetDataFromText();
            travelDetails.setDropoffspot(kutadropoff);
            String numberpas=number_of_passengers;
            passengerholder=numberpas;
            String points=t_price;
            Kutapointholde=points;
            travelDetails.setPickupspot(kutapickup);
            travelDetails.setPassengernum(passengerholder);
            travelDetails.setPickuptime(kutatime);
            travelDetails.setKUtaPoints(Kutapointholde);
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            String userID = user.getUid();
            myRef.child(userID).push().setValue(travelDetails);
            Button order_cab=(Button)v;
            order_cab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " KUTA Ordered. Please wait not less than 15minutes for your taxi to arrive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

public void GetDataFromText() {

    kutadropoff = from_edit_txt.getText().toString();
    kutapickup = to_edit_txt.getText().toString().trim();
    kutatime=time.getText().toString().trim();


}[enter image description here][1]
```

I want there to be no qoutation marks on the values in my database especially figures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `TravelDetails` class defines `kutaPoints` as a `String`, which is then what Firebase writes into the database. If you want to write a number, make sure that `TravelDetails.kutaPoints` is a number:

```
public class TravelDetails {
  private double kutaPoints;

  ...

  public double getKutaPoints() { return this.kutaPoints; }
  public void setKutaPoints(double point) { this.kutaPoints = points; }
  ...
}
```

And then set its value with:

```
travelDetails.setKutaPoints(Double.valueOf(Kutapointholde));
```

Comment: Then what do i do about these lines.               String points =t_price;                  Kutapointholde = points;

Comment: Those can remain the same, as the code in my answer converts their string value to a double when calling `setKutaPoints`.

Answer (score 1):

Those quote marks are just telling you that you wrote a string to the database, rather than a number, which will not have quotes.  They are not part of the literal string values.  If you read the data back out, it will not have the quotes.

Comment: Is there a way i can write the numbers to the database without the use of the quotation marks. Because I am finding challenges reading the numbers with the quotes from the database

Comment: Yes, just provide an int, long, float, or double.  It works exactly like you would expect.  There's nothing special to do.

Comment: 'Points' is a number for example

Comment: Points is not a number type. It's a string.